# Qt removing stretches from a QHBoxLayout

Tags: c++, qt

after adding a stretch with `QBoxLayout::addStretch`, can I then somehow remove it? I want to keep adding a stretch at the end of the layout after every widget I add, so I have to remove the old stretch, add the new widget and add a new stretch after that.

Comment: Can't you use [insertWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qboxlayout.html#insertWidget) to insert the widget at [count](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qboxlayout.html#count) - 2?

Comment: is the stretch actually a widget? also, shouldn't it be -1?

Comment: `delete verticalLayout->takeAt(verticalLayout->count() - 1);`

Comment: @Miki ok it works, but for the first element it adds it and the far right end, don't know why. At first I only add the stretch, then I add the first widget at count() - 1, but it adds it at the wrong place. Every next widget is added properly.

Comment: "If index is negative, the widget is added at the end." I was wrong in the first place, add at index count()-1, as the widget on the right will shift. Sorry :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of removing and adding the stretch at the end, you could start with a layout containing only the stretch.

Then, instead of *adding* the new widget, you insert it at position `layout->count()-1`. The stretch will shift one position to the right.

So:

```
QHBoxLayout* layout = new QHBoxLayout();
layout->addStretch();
setLayout(layout);

...

layout->insertWidget(layout->count()-1, yourWidget);
```